# Django: model ForeignKey from a ForeignKey

Tags: django

I want to do something like this with Django:

Model1 defines several types.

Model2 define a name (the key of Model2) and select one type from Model1.

Model3 get the name and types definited in Model2, and defines other variable.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
  types = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Model2(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  types = models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Model3(models.Model):
  name = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='name')
  types = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='types')
  other = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

"types" from Model3 doesn't work. ¿any idea or alternative? Thanks!!

Error:

```
Reverse query name for 'Model3.name' clashes with field name 'Model2.name'.
    HINT: Rename field 'Model2.name', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Model3.name'.
Reverse accessor for 'Model3.types' clashes with field name 'Model2.types'.
    HINT: Rename field 'Model2.types', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'Model3.types'.
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"?

Comment: you don't need two identical fields in Model3 to get "types" and "name" from Model2. define only on relation to Model2 and get the fields through it

Comment: ¿How can I get the fields through it?

Comment: `mymodel3.name.types`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@IgorMoraru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74479311/django-model-foreignkey-from-a-foreignkey?noredirect=1#comment131476609_74479311) says, it makes no sense to store two references. You can get the `type` by accessing this "through" the `Model2` object. Indeed, the modeling thus should look like:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
  type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Model2(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  type = models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Model3(models.Model):
  name = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  other = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

You can then get `Model1` object associated "through" a `Model2` object of a `Model3` object with:

```
my_model3.name.type
```

or if you want the value stored in the `type` field:

```
my_model3.name.type.type
```

Comment: I have this error: NameError: name 'my_model3' is not defined ¿Where I can use it?

Comment: @ManuelSánchez: `my_model3` is the `Model3` object for which you want to determine the type, so for example thout outcome of a certain query.